# Access Java public static final field from Scala

Tags: java, scala

I want to access a Java public static final field from Scala as follows:

```
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory

//...

val myUrl = WFSDataStoreFactory.URL
```

but whenever I compile I get the error: value URL is not a member of object org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory

Now, according to the documentation at http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/wfs/WFSDataStoreFactory.html#URL, WFSDataStoreFactory.URL is defined as:

```
public static final WFSDataStoreFactory.WFSFactoryParam<URL> URL
```

Any ideas on why I cannot access the URL field?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you have the right version of the library on your classpath?

Comment: Yes, it should definitely work.

Comment: I am sure that I have the correct version of the library. I find that I can create new instances of WFSDataStoreFactory and can call methods on it. However, if I try and create instances of the inner class WFSFactoryParam<T> then I get: "type WFSFactoryParam is not a member of object org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory". I don't know if this is connected with my original URL issue as its type is WFSDataStoreFactory.WFSFactoryParam<URL>.